# Background-repeat Not Working With Div tag

Tags: html, css, image, background

[Link to jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/5bxqjh8u/5/) For some reason, the picture at the top left will not scroll down with the page. However, it looks like one is behind the second one I put in.

What I'm trying to do in my program is keep that picture that the top left even after setting the border and margin to 0px, but also scroll down.

I've seen a few different ways of writing this, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

HTML:

```
<div class="home" style="position: absolute;">
  <a href="hub.html">
   <!--<img src="https://puu.sh/vyv4h/c23b05c784.png">-->
   </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.home {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;

  background-image: url('https://puu.sh/vyv4h/c23b05c784.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Anyone know how my syntax is wrong?

EDIT: I will say though that this syntax does work. Problem is that I cannot get it to work with how my code is currently.

```
body  {
    background-image: url('https://puu.sh/vyv4h/c23b05c784.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

EDIT2: Sorry for the constant edits. I've also tried this:

HTML

```
<img id="home" src="images/home_iconv2.png">
```

CSS:

```
#home {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image to float over the content, you should use `position: fixed` attribute instead of `position: absolute` you've setted both in HTML ...

```
<div class="home" style="position: absolute;"> // <- Here
    <a href="hub.html">
   <img src="https://puu.sh/vyv4h/c23b05c784.png"></a>
</div>
```

And in the CSS

```
.home {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    [...]   
    position: absolute; // <- Here
    z-index: 10;
}
```

My advice would be avoiding writting inline CSS (like you did on the HTML file.) ;)

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much for answering my question!

Comment: You're welcome! Inline css always take over css declared in sheet. Only `!important` can override inline css, that's why we don't recommend using it.

Comment: I will remember your advice about writing inline CSS. I have done it a few times when CSS just wouldn't communicate correctly with my HTML doc. I'm new to both, so it isn't uncommon for me to write one incorrectly, messing everything up. :/

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the background on body:

https://jsfiddle.net/6xj4fjny/

```
body {
  background-image: url('https://puu.sh/vyv4h/c23b05c784.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I made an edit saying it wouldn't work. I shouldn't have posted my question so hastily.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="position:fixed">
    //have a try
</div>
```